# VS2017 кривая кодировка вывода ошибок

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, кодировка

Вот скриншот. Так не всегда, но часто выводит. Как это пофиксить?
[image: кривая кодировка в студии]

Comment: Вторая компиляция помогает, ту же проблему испытываю иногда.

Comment: Ха ты верно подметил) Было такое что после второго раза показывало правильно, но это не тот случай! В этот раз сколько ни на перезапускаю сборку все равно криво(